# How to align the checkbox/radio button elements?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a survey form just for a project on FCC.

I tried putting the `<input>` tag inside `<label>`, also used `<fieldset>` but nothing worked.

```html
<p id="purpose">
  <label for="business"><input id="business" type="radio" name="purpose" value="business" checked> business</label>
  <label for="leisure"><input type="radio" id="leisure" name="purpose" value="leisure">Leisure</label>
  <label for="passingby"><input type="radio" id="passingby" name="purpose" value="passingby">Passing by</label>
  <label for="others"><input type="radio" id="others" name="purpose" value="others">others</label>
</p>

<p class="improve">What do we need to improve?</p>

<label for="food"><input type="checkbox" id="food" name="food">Food</label>

<label for="rooms"><input type="checkbox" id="rooms" name="rooms">Rooms</label>

<label for="service"><input type="checkbox" id="service" name="service">Service</label>

<label for="none"><input type="checkbox" id="none" name="none">None</label>
```

Comment: do you want them to align vertically or horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this

```html
<form action="">

  <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="business"> business<br>
  <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="leisure"> leisure<br>
  <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="passingby"> passingby<br>
  <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="others"> others<br>
</form>

<p class="improve">What do we need to improve?</p>

<label for="food"><input type="checkbox" id="food" name="food">Food</label> <br>

<label for="rooms"><input type="checkbox" id="rooms" name="rooms">Rooms</label><br>

<label for="service"><input type="checkbox" id="service" name="service">Service</label><br>

<label for="none"><input type="checkbox" id="none" name="none">None</label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Label should be sibling of input

```html
<p id="purpose">
  <input id="business" type="radio" name="purpose" value="business" checked><label for="business"> business</label>
  <input type="radio" id="leisure" name="purpose" value="leisure"><label for="leisure">Leisure</label>
  <input type="radio" id="passingby" name="purpose" value="passingby"><label for="passingby">Passing by</label>
  <input type="radio" id="others" name="purpose" value="others"><label for="others">others</label>
</p>
<p class="improve">What do we need to improve?</p>
```

Comment: `Label should be sibling of input`
That is incorrect. Labels can be placed anywhere in the form. Not necessarily within  `input`

Comment: that's right. But if `input` is placed into `label`, no need to use attribute `for`. Since it is used, no need to place `input` inside `label`.